# Dropdown in yii2 Not working

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm trying to bring dropdown in my header. Dropdown label coming. But, dropdwon values not coming. What may be the problem ?

```
<?php

/* @var $this \yii\web\View */
/* @var $content string */

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;
use yii\bootstrap\Dropdown;
use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;
use app\assets\AppAsset;

AppAsset::register($this);
?>

<div class="wrap">
<?php
    NavBar::begin([
    'brandLabel' => 'My Company',
    'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
    ],
    ]);?>

<?
    echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => [
        ['label' => 'Danish Enam', 'url' => ['/site/register']],
        ['label' => 'Dropdown', 'url' => ['#'],
         ['label' => 'DropdownA', 'url' => '/'],
             ['label' => 'DropdownB', 'url' => '#'],
        ],
    ],
    ]);
NavBar::end();
?>
```

Here is screenshot. 
You all can clearly see. Dropdown coming in header. Right to 'My Company' Text. But, no values are coming. Not clickable.
[image]

Any Idea ?

[image]

Comment: check this link <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30206337/yii2-navbar-with-dropdown">Link</a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply use another `Nav` widget instead of `Dropdown` :

```
NavBar::begin([
    'brandLabel' => 'My Company',
    'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
    ],
]);

echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-left',
    ],
    'items' => [
        [
            'label' => 'Dropdown',
            'url' => '#',
            'items' => [
                ['label' => 'DropdownA', 'url' => '/'],
                ['label' => 'DropdownB', 'url' => '#'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Still DropdownA, DropdwonB values not coming Mr @Soju

Comment: No Error Showing In Console

Comment: It works... Show me your updated code and the output of the Nav widget.

Comment: Hey @Soju. I Edited My Question. Last Image Is Output.

Comment: Yeah. Updated Mr @Soju.

Comment: Whatever code, you gave me. I Pasted it. echo Nav::widget is there.

Comment: ... Well, did you really test my code ?? (and please remove your previous comments)

Comment: Yes. Same Code I Pasted. And, Tested Too.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code :

```
echo '<ul id="navbar-id" class="navbar-nav navbar-right nav">';
echo '<li class="dropdown">';
echo '<a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Label <b class="caret"></b></a>';

echo Dropdown::widget([
    'items' => [
        ['label' => 'DropdownA', 'url' => '/'],
        ['label' => 'DropdownB', 'url' => '#'],
    ],
]);

echo '</li>';
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: DropdownA, DropdownB values are not coming. Means, not acting as dropdown. Not clickable @Hiren.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

/* @var $this \yii\web\View */
/* @var $content string */

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;
use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;
use app\assets\AppAsset;

AppAsset::register($this);
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>

<div class="wrap">
    <?php
    NavBar::begin([
        'brandLabel' => 'My Company',
        'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
        ],
    ]);


    echo Nav::widget([
        'items' => [
            [
                'label' => 'Home',
                'url' => ['site/index'],
                'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post'],
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'Dropdown',
                'items' => [
                     ['label' => 'Level 1 - Dropdown A', 'url' => '#'],
                     '<li class="divider"></li>',

                     ['label' => 'Level 1 - Dropdown B', 'url' => '#'],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'Login',
                'url' => ['site/login'],
                'visible' => Yii::$app->user->isGuest
            ],
        ],
        'options' => ['class' =>'nav-pills'], // set this to nav-tab to get tab-styled navigation
    ]);


    NavBar::end();
    ?>

    <div class="container">
        <?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
            'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
        ]) ?>
        <?= $content ?>
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="pull-left">&copy; My Company <?= date('Y') ?></p>

        <p class="pull-right"><?= Yii::powered() ?></p>
    </div>
</footer>

<?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

this is an entire layout code. try this layout for any view it will surely work. first name this file header.php(any name is ok) then select the view file for which u want this layout with  dropdown.

Comment: Still Not working Ajith. Not getting my mistake. I used your code. But, not worked. Is any where i've to include any code ?

Answer (score 0):

small error in your code :

```
NavBar::begin([
'brandLabel' => 'My Company',
'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
'options' => [
    'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
],
]);


echo Nav::widget([
'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
'items' => [
    ['label' => 'Danish Enam', 'url' => ['/site/register']],
    ['label' => 'Dropdown',
        'items' => [
            ['label' => 'DropdownA', 'url' => '/'],
            ['label' => 'DropdownB', 'url' => '#'],
        ],
    ],
],
]);

NavBar::end();
```

Then the bad new, there is a limitation with bootstrap, you can only have 2 levels for the dropdown not 3.

If you want more information take a look there :

[Multilevel Boostrap Menu in Yii 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29135604/multilevel-boostrap-menu-in-yii-2)